# Listas aninhadas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso de uma ajuda,digamos que eu tenha a seguinte lista:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7,8,9],10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

Se eu quiser imprimir cada um dos itens dessa lista eu faria um:

```
for i in lista:
   print(lista)
```

Até ai tudo certo.
Porém,queria saber como eu posso fazer o mesmo para a lista que está dentro da lista.

Eu pensei no seguinte código,entretanto,não está funcionando:

```
   for i in lista:
      for i in lista:
          print(i)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode resolver utilizando recursividade. Cria uma função para imprimir a lista, e sempre que cada elemento dessa lista é outra lista volta a chamar a mesma função sobre esse elemento.

Para saber se um elemento é uma lista pode utilizar a função [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) passando como segundo argumento `list`.

Exemplo:

```
def imprimir_lista(lista):
    for elemento in lista:
        if isinstance(elemento, list): # se este elemento é uma lista, chama a mesma funçao
            imprimir_lista(elemento)
        else: # caso contrário imprime normalmente
            print(elemento)
```

Saída:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7,8,9],10,11,12,13,14,15]
>>> imprimir_lista(lista)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Veja outro exemplo com uma lista ainda mais aninhada:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]]
>>> imprimir_lista(lista)
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

[Veja o código a executar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/w6RC7g)

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, a sua variável **i** está sendo sobrescrita, deveria usar outra variável, além de você iterar novamente na lista original, quando deveria iterar sobre a var i somente quando é uma **list**. O segundo **for** deveria somente ser feito se o elemento da lista original for do tipo list, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7,8,9],10,11,12,13,14,15]

for elemento in lista:
    if isinstance(elemento, list):
        for subelemento in elemento:
            print(subelemento)
    else:
        print(elemento)
```

A função isinstance() verifica se o elemento é um list para assim fazer o laço, senão imprime o elemento normalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Se deseja imprimir individualmente os elementos de uma sequencia irregular simples, sequencia formada de sequencias regulares, uma opção é achatar essa sequencia para imprimir individualmente os elementos da forma que o convier.

Para achatar uma sequencia irregular simples, pode-se utilizar o método de classe [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) que é usado para encadear os elementos de um iterável constituído por iteráveis.

Como argumento é passado para `chain.from_iterable()` uma compreensão de lista que percorre uma sequencia verificando se cada elemento também uma sequencia. Se o elemento for uma sequencia apenas o copia, senão o converte em tupla dele mesmo resultando em lista de sequencias:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections.abc import Sequence

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7,8,9],10,11,12,13,14,15]

l = chain.from_iterable([e if isinstance(e, Sequence) else (e,) for e in lista])

print(*l, sep="\n")
```

No caso de uma sequencia irregular composta, sequencia formada de sequencias regulares e irregulares, usa-se um algoritmo recursivo similar ao anterior que ao se deparar com uma sequencia aninhada previamente a achata:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections.abc import Sequence

lista = [1,[(2,[[[3]]])],4,5,[[6,7,[8,9]]],10,11,[[[12]]],(13,14,15)]

def achatar(l):
  return chain.from_iterable([achatar(e) if isinstance(e, Sequence) else (e,) for e in l])

l= achatar(lista)

print(*l, sep="\n")
```

Algoritmo que pode convertido em uma expressão lambda:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections.abc import Sequence

lista = [1,[(2,[[[3]]])],4,5,[[6,7,[8,9]]],10,11,[[[12]]],(13,14,15)]

(achatar:= lambda l: chain.from_iterable([achatar(e) if isinstance(e, Sequence) else (e,) for e in l]))

l= achatar(lista)

print(*l, sep="\n")
```

<sup>Teste os algoritmos no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/ListasIrregulares)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [pydash](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import pydash
lista = [[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
lista2 =  [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7,8,9],10,11,12,13,14,15]
lista3 = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]]

print(pydash.flatten_deep(lista))
print()
print(pydash.flatten_deep(lista2))
print()
print(pydash.flatten_deep(lista3))
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```